# How can I change the output display of my pagination?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using paginate_links.

Right now i have:

`Page 1 of 6` 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... `»`

`Page 3 of 6` `«` 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... `»`

`Page 6 of 6` `«` ..., 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

```
<div class="pagination">
   <span class="pages">
      <?php if( empty( $var ) ) {
         global $wp_query;
         if( !isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) )
               return;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
      }
      else {
         global $$var;
               if( !is_a( $$var, 'WP_Query' ) )
                  return;
         if( !isset( $$var->max_num_pages ) || !isset( $$var ) )
               return;
         $pages = absint( $$var->max_num_pages );
      }
      if( $pages < 1 )
         return;
      $page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
      echo 'Page ' . $page . ' of ' . $pages; ?>
   </span>
   <?php       
   global $wp_query;
         $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
         echo paginate_links( array(
            'mid_size'      => 2,
            'prev_text'     => __('«'),
            'next_text'     => __('»'),
            'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'        => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'         => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
         ) );
      ?> 
</div>
```

How can I add `"last"` and `"first"` link to achieve the following pagination style?

`Page 1 of 20` 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... `»` `Last »`

`Page 10 of 20` `« First` `«` 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ... `»` `Last »`

`Page 20 of 20` `« First` `«` ..., 16, 17, 18, 19, 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this function to the active theme's functions.php file

```
function tutsocean_pagination( $range = 5 ) {
    global $paged, $wp_query;
    if ( !$max_page )
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if ( $max_page > 1 )
        if ( !$paged ) $paged = 1;
    echo "\n".'<ul class="dcs_pagination">'."\n";
    if ( $paged != 1 )
        echo '<li class="page-num page-num-first"><a href='.get_pagenum_link(1).'>'.__('« First', "PAGE_LANG").' </a></li>';
    echo '<li class="page-num page-num-prev">';
    previous_posts_link(' &laquo; '); 
    echo '</li>';
    if ( $max_page > $range ) :
        if ( $paged < $range ) :
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= ($range + 1); $i++ ) {
                $class = $i == $paged ? 'current' : '';
                echo '<li class="page-num"><a class="paged-num-link '.$class.'" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'"> '.$i.' </a></li>';
            }
        elseif ( $paged >= ( $max_page - ceil($range/2)) ) :
            for ( $i = $max_page - $range; $i <= $max_page; $i++ ){
                $class = $i == $paged ? 'current' : '';
                echo '<li class="page-num"><a class="paged-num-link '.$class.'" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'"> '.$i.' </a></li>';
            }
        endif;

    elseif ( $paged >= $range && $paged < ( $max_page - ceil($range/2)) ) :
        for ( $i = ($paged - ceil($range/2)); $i <= ($paged + ceil($range/2)); $i++ ) {
            $class = $i == $paged ? 'current' : '';
            echo '<li class="page-num"><a class="paged-num-link '.$class.'" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'"> '.$i.' </a></li>';
        }

    else :
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $max_page; $i++ ) {
            $class = $i == $paged ? 'current' : '';
            echo '<li class="page-num"><a class="paged-num-link '.$class.'" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'"> '.$i.' </a></li>';
        }
    endif;
    echo '<li class="page-num page-num-next">';
    next_posts_link(' &raquo; '); 
    echo '</li>';
    if ( $paged != $max_page )
        echo '<li class="page-num page-num-last"><a href='.get_pagenum_link($max_page).'> '.__('Last »', "PAGE_LANG").'</a></li>';

    echo "\n".'</ul>'."\n";
}
```

After that, add the following code where you want to show the pagination.

```
<div class="pagination">
   <span class="pages">
      <?php if( empty( $var ) ) {
         global $wp_query;
         if( !isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) )
               return;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
      }
      else {
         global $$var;
               if( !is_a( $$var, 'WP_Query' ) )
                  return;
         if( !isset( $$var->max_num_pages ) || !isset( $$var ) )
               return;
         $pages = absint( $$var->max_num_pages );
      }
      if( $pages < 1 )
         return;
      $page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
      echo 'Page ' . $page . ' of ' . $pages; ?>
   </span>
   <?php tutsocean_pagination(); ?> 
</div>
```

A bit of optional CSS. Ignore if you want to add your own CSS/styles

```
ul.dcs_pagination {list-style: none;display: flex;}
.pagination {
    display: flex;
}
ul.dcs_pagination li {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

The best part of this code is you can make changes to Next previous buttons or first last buttons in the function defination of `tutsocean_pagination()`

Comment: Perfect, I had a warning caused by PAGE_LANG. If I remove it, everything seems work very well.
Is supposed for me to remove it or to change it?

Comment: I have updated the code and replace PAGE_LANG with "PAGE_LANG". Actually, it is the language constraint used in case people want to add multiple language support. If you didn't understand this then just copy the code and use it as it is and everything will work fine.